# Having trouble rearranging first array in accordance to second array

Tags: c, arrays, vector

I am trying to rearrange my first array (vector1) in accordance to the sequence of the indices second array (vector2)

For example, if:
vector1 = 1 2 3 4
and vector2 = 0 3 1 2

my desired output should be:
1 4 2 3

However, the execution of my code is continuously interrupted due to using an "illegal array index." Would someone be able to point out where I am going wrong? Thanks so much in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {

int n;

printf("Enter vector length: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

printf("Enter vector: ");

int vector1[n];

int i = 0;
while (i < n) {
scanf("%d", &vector1[i]);
i++;
}

printf("Enter permutation: ");

int vector2[n];

i = 0;
int j = 0;
while (i < n) {
scanf("%d", &vector2[j]);

i++;
}

i = 0;
int vector3[n];
while (i < n) {
vector3[i] = vector1[vector2[i]];
i++;
}

printf("%d", vector3[i]);


}
```

Comment: When reading `vector2` you use j instead of i so your array will not contain the data you think. Always use a debugger to step through your code to see what is happening. Also the while loops would look better as for loops usually

Comment: Even when I corrected that, it still says I am using an illegal array index.

Comment: In the end you’re printing out the fifth element of four element array. Please do run the code in a debugger when errors occur

Comment: How do I run the code in a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

While using `vector2` you are getting the value of `vector2[j]` but increasing the value of `i`. You have assigned `j=0` above so the loop is scanning the same value again and again i.e `vector2[0]` until the loop goes off. So to correct your program either you increase `j` in your loop by replacing `j++` instead of `i++` or you can just replace `vector2[j]` with `vector2[i]` in the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int n;

    printf("Enter vector length: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter vector: ");
    int vector1[n];

    int i = 0;
    while (i < n) 
    {
        scanf("%d", &vector1[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("Enter permutation: ");
    int vector2[n];
    i = 0;
    while (i < n) 
    {
        scanf("%d", &vector2[i]);
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    int vector3[n];
    while (i < n) 
    {
        vector3[i] = vector1[vector2[i]];
        i++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%d", vector3[i]);
}
```